# Getting value from NSDictionary (nested) to array in the same order

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a problem in parsing json in array. I am able to parse the response coming from json to NSDictionary.

```
{
    13: {
            "name":alok1, 
            "class":inter1
    }, 
    14: {
            "name":alok2, 
            "class":inter2
    },
    12: {
            "name":alok, 
            "class":inter
    }
}
```

i have to add values in array alok1, alok2, alok3 in the order they are appearing in response. If I use all keys and try to get object on basis of all key it is coming like alok, alok1, alok2(sorted order), but I need to maintain alok1, alok2, alok3  order. how to achieve this?

Comment: can you show the code what you have tried? You can get the values in NSMutableArray and shift (insert or delete values) the array if it is just single value you have to adjust.

Comment: Please use proper formatting next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dictionary is always printed sorted by Keys** and you cant modify it to print based on values.

So if you outer dictionary's keys are 13, 14, 12. It will print by 12, 13 and 14. Then correspondingly the nested dictionary values based on the keys.

So resulting in alok, alok1 and alok2.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot order a NSDictionary, if you want an ordered collection you need to store it in a NSArray and sort it by the key.

Comment: not getting you.sorry:(,i m not trying to order i just want to get in same order it is appearing in dictionary.